# Is referential integrity supported?

Tags: 8

Does Drupal 8 support referential integrity? Can I tell Drupal what it should do if a parent row in a content type is deleted? For example:

- I could tell Drupal not to allow the deletion of a parent row if it has child rows
- I could tell Drupal to delete all child rows that belong to a parent row when that parent row is deleted

By *row* I mean an item of a content type. For example, if the content type is *Book*, a row is the data about one book.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! I must admit I don't understand your question. What rows?

Comment: @leymannx I think they are called "nodes" in Drupal, not sure.

Comment: Are you sure, then please update your question accordingly. Otherwise it would be better to find that out yourself first and then come back and clarify.

Comment: You should simply try it out yourself. What happens when you try to delete a node that's referenced by another node? Does it work? As far as I remember this isn't possible. But I might be wrong. Please just try it out yourself instead of letting us try it out for you.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no such feature out of the box.

For D7, there is a module for that, but I haven't see a Drupal 8 version: https://www.drupal.org/project/erri.

We did build something like that ourself based on the entity_usage module, we alter the node delete form and display a warning that shows where the node is used.

Comment: A Drupal 8 module which facilitates the enforcement of entity references is https://www.drupal.org/project/erg. It is abandoned but the approach taken seems solid enough.