# How to display current pages the media entity is referenced during deletion?

Tags: 8, entities, hooks, media

We are using [Media Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_entity) module that provides a `Document` media bundle. On our `Article` content type, we have created an Entity Reference field to `Media` that is set to `Document` media bundle.

When you click Delete on this `Document` media entity, you are taken to a `Are you sure you want to delete the media <media name>?` page for confirmation (not sure of the official name, but let's call it Confirm Deletion page). On this page we would like to display all the pages where this media entity is currently being referenced.

How would we display the list of nodes that are referencing the media that content editors are attempting to delete?

Comment: Basically the same question as https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/269706/is-referential-integrity-supported, yours is just a specific use case of the general concept asked about there, but the answers there apply too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additionally to the comment, here's the snippet we used based on the entity_usage module in a hook_form_alter():

```
  $object = $form_state->getFormObject();
  if ($object instanceof ContentEntityDeleteForm) {
    $entity = $object->getEntity();
    $usage_data = \Drupal::service('entity_usage.usage')->listSources($entity);

    if (!empty($usage_data)) {
      $count = 0;

      foreach ($usage_data as $usage) {
        $count += count($usage);
      }

      $form['usage_warning_message'] = [
        '#type' => 'container',
        '#markup' => t('This content is used in <a href="@usage_url" target="_blank">@count</a> places.', [
          '@usage_url' => Url::fromRoute('entity_usage.usage_list', [
            'entity_type' => $entity->getEntityTypeId(),
            'entity_id' => $entity->id(),
          ])->toString(),
          '@count' => $count,
        ]),
        '#attributes' => [
          'class' => ['messages', 'messages--warning'],
        ],
        '#weight' => -100,
      ];
    }
  }
```

Comment: this was super helpful as it lead to other conversations about the delete form. Additionally, I saw your comment on the other question as well.